# Importing CSS in JSP tags

Tags: html, css, jsp, jsp-tags

What are some ways (if any) to link or import a style sheet from a JSP tag called in the <body>? It would be great if I can encapsulate all necessary imports in the JSP tag.

#### Current State

**index.jsp:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- we have to know what css file somecontent uses and include it here -->
        <!-- the tag below prints <link rel="/somecontent.css"... /> but makes sure this url is only included once -->
        <x:requireOnce loc="/somecontent.css" type="css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <x:somecontent />
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Goal

**index.jsp:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <%-- nothing for somecontent tag here --%>
    </head>
    <body>
        <x:somecontent />
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

**somecontent.tag:**

```
<%@ tag description="some independent content" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%-- the inline attribute will indicate that it is in the body and shouldn't use <link> which won't work here --%>
<x:requireOnce loc="/somecontent.css" type="css" inline="true" />
<%-- this will print <script type="text/javascript" src="/somecontent.js" ...></script> --%>
<x:requireOnce loc="/somecontent.js" type="js" />
...
```

Is there a way to keep a reference to the position in the head tag within the JspWriter and insert content there when necessary, i.e. new link tags?

Ideally, I don't want to inline the contents of the stylesheet or use javascript to include the style sheet. Hopefully there's some way with @import, <link> or some JSP magic... Thoughts?

Comment: You're basically reinventing what already exist in some component based MVC frameworks, such as JSF which has a [`<h:outputStylesheet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html) tag for this purpose (and [`<h:outputScript>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) for JS). I suggest to have a look at that instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks, BalusC. I am not sure if we can switch over to JSF. Do you know of any ways to do the same thing using only JSP and Spring MVC?

Comment: Everything is possible. For some cases you just have to write more code yourself than other cases. Sorry, I can't post an answer in detail as I'm not really into JSP tags and Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of what SiteMesh does.

Each `requireOnce` tag would just put the file to link to in a list of files, stored in a request attribute. A servlet filter would buffer the whole response, and rewrite it when completed with the head section rewritten to include all the links.

Comment: Thanks JB, that sounds doable. That might be what I'll end up going with.

Comment: Went with this solution. Unfortunately, I had to write more code than desired to reinvent this wheel without JSF but it seems to be the only way.